# VLOOKUP when VLookup Value is a cell populated via another formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, cells

I keep getting a return of NA when trying to accomplish the following:
formula:

```
=vlookup(left(Q2,3),A2:C20,3,false)
```

Definitions:

`Q2` is a cell that is populated from a formula. Its calculated value is  `111-0021-12345`

Column A is a part list which includes the value `111`

Column C is a list that associates the column A numbers to supplier names.

If I just manually enter `111` in any cell and use that cell as my "lookup value" the formula returns the correct supplier name. But, when the "Lookup Value" is from a cell that is populated from a formula I get `#NA`. The lookup value cell IS being populated correctly.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?  I am using Windows 7 and Excel 2010.

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT` function always returns a text value, try adding zero within the formula to make it numeric....then the `VLOOKUP` should work as required, i.e.

=VLOOKUP(LEFT(Q2,3)**+0**,A2:C20,3,FALSE)

Comment: Does VLOOKUP always require a numeric value for the lookup? Because I swear I've done it without...

Comment: @nhinkle it just needs the `lookup_value` format to match the `table_array` format. [More info](http://www.onenotegem.com/onenote-batch.html). For this one, it was looking for a text value in a numeric column.

Answer (score 1):

Barry houdini's identified the problem: for your table, you need a numeric lookup value, but the `LEFT` function returns text. Another way to fix your formula is to wrap the lookup value in a `VALUE()` function. This will transform the text inside it to a numeric value.

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(Q2,3)),A2:C20,3,FALSE)
```